# EGL_BAD_DISPLAY in android whilst debugging webview

Tags: android, webview

Running webview in android in the app

The error is an EGL_BAD_DISPLAY. There have been a few references to the issues such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144629/bizarre-error-related-to-webview-in-android-app) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34151693/unfortunately-my-app-has-stopped-after-using-phonegap), but these have not been useful so far (these have included adding transparent background (see the .java) and hardware acceleration (see .xml). Internet permission is enabled in the manifest.

I am debugging on a physical device, android version 5.0.2, Samsung tablet Tab 4.

Debug error log

```
10-19 16:32:58.757 28363-28363/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
10-19 16:32:58.757 28363-28363/? E/Zygote: v2
10-19 16:32:58.767 28363-28363/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
10-19 16:33:03.267 28363-28657/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
```

.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_demo_home);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/MyMap8.html");
    myWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

    // Other AWS gibberish
```

.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Solution was to use Web**Chrome**Client (import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;) rather than Web**View**Client

Comment: I am running into the same issue. I tried using WebChormeClient. But it still does not load.

Comment: Or you can use both :)

Comment: WebChromeClient it is not helping, still same error